# Parse JSON with mixed key value pairs and arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Unable to parse mixed key/value pairs with arrays in the middle. I can either get only the key/values or only get the array but not both.

I tried following the documentation at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm but did not find an example that matches my need.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ParsingJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // code to deserialize from JSON string to a typed object
            string json = @"{
    'TransferResult': 'SUCCESS',
    'City': 'California',
    'State': 'CA',
    'Applications': [
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3531'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3263'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3251','OfficialResult' : 'PENDING'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3228'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX9521'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3251','OfficialResult' : 'APPROVED'},

    ]}";

            Application app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>(json);

            if(app.TransferResult == "SUCCESS")
            {
                // if TransferResult == SUCCESS
                // grab the City, State, AppSerial, and OfficialResult if any
                Console.WriteLine(app.City);
                Console.WriteLine(app.State);
                Console.WriteLine(app.AppSerial); // make key value pairs of AppSerial and values and OfficialResults and results
                Console.WriteLine(app.OfficialResult); // if any
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



        } // Main
        public class Application
        {
            public string TransferResult { get; set; } //SUCCESS or FAIL
            public string City { get; set; } // California.
            public string State { get; set; } // CA
            public string AppSerial { get; set; } // APX12345
            public string OfficialResult { get; set; } // APPROVED, PENDING, ADOPTED
        } //Application

    } // Program
} //namespace
```

I would like to get the JSON City, State, and the AppSerials for the City along with the OfficialResult if any. Right now I'm getting just the City, State, and nothing for the AppSerials.

Comment: Welcome muchacho! Your `Application` class doesn't quite match up with the structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ParsingJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // code to deserialize from JSON string to a typed object
            string json = @"{
    'TransferResult': 'SUCCESS',
    'City': 'California',
    'State': 'CA',
    'Applications': [
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3531'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3263'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3251','OfficialResult' : 'PENDING'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3228'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX9521'},
        {'AppSerial' : 'APX3251','OfficialResult' : 'APPROVED'},

    ]}";

            Application app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>(json);

            if(app.TransferResult == "SUCCESS")
            {
                // if TransferResult == SUCCESS
                // grab the City, State, AppSerial, and OfficialResult if any
                Console.WriteLine(app.City);
                Console.WriteLine(app.State);
                Console.WriteLine(app.AppSerial); // make key value pairs of AppSerial and values and OfficialResults and results
                Console.WriteLine(app.OfficialResult); // if any
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



        } // Main

        public class Application
        {
            public string TransferResult { get; set; } //SUCCESS or FAIL
            public string City { get; set; } // California.
            public string State { get; set; } // CA
            public List<ApplicationDetail> Applications { get; set; }
        } //Application

        public class ApplicationDetail
        {
            public string AppSerial { get; set; }
            public string OfficialResult { get; set; }
        } // ApplicationDetail

    } // Program
} //namespace
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was able to make it work using a foreach loop in the ApplicationDetail.    foreach(var i in app.Applications)
    {
     Console.WriteLine($"AppSerial:{i.AppSerial} Result: {i.OfficialResult}");
    }

Answer (score 1):

your actual class is needed to be

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string TransferResult { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Application[] Applications { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public string AppSerial { get; set; }
    public string OfficialResult { get; set; }
}
```

and you need to deserialize in this way

```
Rootobject app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: Enlightning! How can I retrieve the values from the Application? Can you please post an example? Thank you!